# Foundation accordion not working on AJAX loaded data

Tags: jquery, ajax, zurb-foundation

I'm writing a simple todo API. I am currently working on the web browser client app. After the user logs in, they are taken to a page that shows all of their todo items along with an 'add new' button. I do the initial data load with AJAX and place the results in `<ul class="accordion" id="results" data-accordion></ul>`

However, after the data loads, the accordion doesn't seem to work properly. I can successfully collapse the first item, but can't reopen it. Here is my relevant jQuery code:

```
var ajaxurl = 'todo-tasks.php';
var results = $('#results');
$(function() {
    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    $(document).foundation();
    load();

    $('#add-form').submit(function() {
        create();
    });

    function load() {
        var params = { action : 'readall'};
        $.post(ajaxurl, params, function(data) {
            var json = JSON.parse(data);
            //console.log(json);

            $.each(json, function(i, item) {
                var id = item.todo_id;
                var title = item.title;
                var status = item.is_done;
                var user_id = item.user_id;
                var due_date = item.due_date;
                var description = item.description;
                var lblclass, text, active;

                if ( status ) {
                    lblclass = ' success';
                    text = 'Completed';
                }

                else {
                    lblclass = ' alert';
                    text = 'Not Finished';
                }

                if ( i == 0 ) {
                    active = ' active';
                }

                else {
                    active = '';
                }

                var html = '<li class="accordion-navigation">';
                html += '<a href="#panel' + i + 'b">' + title + '<span class="label right' + lblclass + '">' + text + '</span></a>'
                html += '<div id="#panel' + i + 'b" class="content' + active + '">';
                html += '<p><strong>Due Date: </strong><br />' + due_date + '</p>';
                html += '<p><strong>Description: </strong><br />' + description + '</p>';
                html += '<div class="right">';
                html += '<a href="#" class="delete button small alert">Delete</a> ';
                html += '<a href="#" class="edit button small secondary">Edit</a>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</div>';
                html += '</li>';

                results.append(html);
                $(document).foundation('accordion', 'reflow');
            });



        }); 
    }
```

Do you see something wrong with this that would prevent the accordion from functioning properly?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I feel dumb.

`<div id="#panel...` didn't need the `#` there..